# What is a good way to think of these layout contraints

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am learning about layout constraints and find it a bit confusing why the last line of NSLayout Constraints for the trailing anchor mentions a view instead of loginView? Is there any good logical way to think of this? Struggling to imagine what is written.

```
let loginView = LoginView()


view.addSubview(loginView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            loginView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            loginView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 1),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: loginView.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 1)
        ])
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the "flipping" between:

```
loginView.leadingAnchor.constraint(...)
```

and:

```
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(...)
```

Both of these sets of constraints will give the same result:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    loginView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
    loginView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

    loginView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

    loginView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        
])
```

---

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
    loginView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
    loginView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        
    loginView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
        
])
```

In each case, we're telling auto-layout to put the trailing-edge of `loginView` **8-points from the trailing-edge of** `view`.

Which approach to use really comes down to individual preference: Do I like using all **Positive** values, with order-flipping? Or do I like using **Positive** values for "left-side" constraints and **Negative** values for "right-side" constraints without order-flipping (obviously, flip the terminology for LTR locales).

Starting with iOS 11, Apple added the concept of ***system spacing*** - which changes based on device size, accessibility options, etc - which we can use instead of hard-coded values.

We have `equalToSystemSpacingAfter` (and `equalToSystemSpacingBelow`), but we do **not** have `equalToSystemSpacingBefore` (or `equalToSystemSpacingAbove`).

So, if we want to use ***system spacing***, we must "flip" the constraint order:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
    loginView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    loginView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
        
    loginView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 1),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: loginView.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 1),
        
])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is defining a set of layout constraints for the loginView object. The constraints specify how the `loginView` should be positioned within its parent view.

In the last line of the code, the `view.trailingAnchor` is being used as the reference for the trailing edge of the `loginView`. This means that the `loginView` will be positioned such that its trailing edge is aligned with the trailing edge of the parent view.

In general, when working with layout constraints, it is important to think about the relationship between the views being constrained and the constraints themselves. In this case, the `loginView` is the view being constrained, and the constraints are defining how the `loginView` should be positioned relative to its parent view.

Comment: I believe I understand what you're saying, but logically wouldn't it make more sense to set the trailing Anchor constraint for the loginView rather than the parent view. To clarify, is there a way to say...trailing anchor... this much away from parent?

Comment: It seems like we are flipping the constraint rules, I just don't quite undertstand why

Answer (score 0):

`view` means `self.view`. This is a UIViewController; it has a view. This is the view that will contain the `loginView`; you can actually see the `loginView` being added to the view controller's view as a subview, right there in the code.

So this code inserts the `loginView` into `self.view` and then proceeds to describe the physical relationship between their sizes and positions.

Comment: Hi Matt, I believe I understand what you're saying but I'm not quite sure why we are "flipping" for a lack of a better word the constraint rule when setting the trailing anchor? In my mind setting a distance from child to parent view makes more sense.

Comment: It's arbitrary. Either way will do. The operation is commutative. :)